# Start and shutdown Spring application context in a unit test

Tags: spring, junit5, spring-test

What's the recommended way to start and gracefully shutdown a Spring application within a unit test? I am aware of the SpringExtension for JUnit5, but that starts and stops the Spring context before/after the test method execution.

I would like to start and stop the spring context withing the test method as I would like to verify that certain methods are called (especially during shutdown).

Is there a recommended way how to achieve that?

Comment: Hi there. For clarification is this a SpringBoot application with a built in server?

Comment: Yes, it's a Spring Boot app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test shutdown callbacks, you're probably better of creating and shutting down the `ApplicationContext` directly within your tests instead of letting the Spring TestContext Framework manage the context for you.

You might also find the [AssertJ support in Spring Boot Test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/assertj) useful.

Comment: Handy, I have not been aware of the AssertJ support in Spring Boot. Thanks for the pointer!